# Spring WebArgumentResolver not resolving?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, resolver

I'm using custom argument resolvers with spring 3.2.4 and everything works fine until now. 
every now and then I notice that one of my servers is not resolving arguments properly and I was wondering, is there anything I'm doing wrong in the configuration.

Couple of things to mentions - I something use several custom arguments in a method 
e.g

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String editMode(@LoggedInUser User user, @UserCompany Company company) throws IOException
```

and the arguments that are not being resolved are always not the first argument..

any chance I'm missing something in terms of ordering? priority to resolvers?

-- EDIT

My argument resolver is

```
public class MyHRCompanyResolver implements WebArgumentResolver {


@Inject
private CompanyService companyService;


public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter methodParameter, NativeWebRequest nativeWebRequest) throws Exception {

    MyHRCompany myHRCompany = methodParameter.getParameterAnnotation(MyHRCompany.class);

    if (myHRCompany == null){
        return UNRESOLVED;
    }

    try {

        Company company = companyService.userCompany(getUser());
        if (company == null)
            return UNRESOLVED;

        return company;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // log some error
        return UNRESOLVED;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Let's see your argument resolver. Let's see the argument it's meant to resolve.

Comment: edited to including the code